# Optimizing conversion to ascii

Tags: php, ascii

I want to convert all characters in a string to ascii codes, and right now I do this with `ord()` function - but it is pretty slow. Is there another, faster way to do this?

I have ~100GB of text on which I'd have to use this convertion, so this little difference matters a lot.

I've been thinking about creating a map of ascii characters and using it instead, but I'm not sure if it will be faster, and I couldn't find ascii map anywhere.

Comment: `ord()` works with a weird combination of 7-bit ASCII and some undisclosed single-byte encoding and is of course useless in our modern age of Unicode. What's your ultimate goal? If you only want to get an hexadecimal dump of some binary string there might be better alternatives.

Comment: This sounds like it might be a case of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) :) Do you need to switch between encodings? Do you need, for some reason, a huge file with the ascii codes? Hex or decimal? Comma separated?

Comment: Agree the problem needs clarification, but if speed is a constraint, and the task is cpu bound, php is probably a poor choice, unless the problem is handled almost entirely by a built in (eg C code) function

Comment: I will need to convert URLs to binary and save bytes to file. URLs will contain only 7-bit ASCII, so it should be enough.

Comment: I know php is a poor choice, but all my files are encoded CSVs with PHP, and PHP has a bug - https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=43225 - which makes other languages throw errors :)

Comment: But `ord()` also returns a decimal number which can have 1, 2 or 3 digits. How do you currently save that into a file while being able to tell out individual digits? Do you use a separator?